# Product category not organized when creating menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu, woocommerce-theming, megamenu

My product categories are added but when I intended to create a menu from the product categories from Appearence>>Menus the, the product categories section not showing all the categories of my stores[image]

[image]

it also not following the hierarchical structure of the categories.

[image]
[image]